# For spark applications running on YARN, which deploy mode is better - client or cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I understand the major differences between client and cluster mode for Spark applications on YARN.

Major differences include

1. **Where do the driver run** - Local in clinet mode, Application Master in cluster mode
2. **Client running duration** - In clinet mode, client needs to run for entire duration, 
   In cluster mode, client need not run as AM takes care of it
3. **Interactive usage** - spark shell and pyspark. Cluster mode is not suited well as these
   require the driver to be run on client
4. **Scheduling work** - In client mode, the client schedules the work by communicating directly with the containers. 
   In cluster mode, A schedules the work by communicating directly with the containers

In both cases for similarities

1. **Who handles the executor requests from the YARN** - Application master
2. **Who starts the executor processes** - YARN Node Manager

My question is - In real world scenarios( production environment), where we do not need interactive mode, client not requiring to run for long duration - is the cluster mode an obvious choice?

Are there any benefits for client mode like:

- to run the driver on client machine rather than AM
- to allow client to schedule work, rather than AM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation,

> A common deployment strategy is to submit your application from a
>   gateway machine that is physically co-located with your worker
>   machines (e.g. Master node in a standalone EC2 cluster). In this
>   setup, client mode is appropriate. In client mode, the driver is
>   launched directly within the client spark-submit process, with the
>   input and output of the application attached to the console. Thus,
>   this mode is especially suitable for applications that involve the
>   REPL (e.g. Spark shell).
>
> Alternatively, if your application is submitted from a machine far
>   from the worker machines (e.g. locally on your laptop), it is common
>   to use cluster mode to minimize network latency between the drivers
>   and the executors. Note that cluster mode is currently not supported
>   for standalone clusters, Mesos clusters, or python applications.

Looks like, the main reason is when we run the spark-submit from remote, to reduce the latency between executors and driver, cluster mode is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, in production environment the only resonable mode is cluster-mode with 2 exceptions:

- when hadoop nodes does not have resources needed by application, for example: at the end of execution spark job performs `ssh` to server that is not accessible from hadoop nodes
- when you use spark streaming and you want to shut it gracefully (killing cluster-mode application forces the streaming to close and if you run in client-mode you can call `ssc.stop(stopGracefully = true)`